# Space between echoed values from db

Tags: php, html

I have a question about some code I have written. The code echos two columns from a database into a form. I cannot separate the two in the form. Like if their name was John Deer it echos JohnDeer. So I need a way of creating a space in my code. Any tips?

```
  "<?= $first_name, $last_name ?>
  <span class="error"><?= $name_error ?>
```

Comment: It's not meant as an insult, but what about adding a space? https://php.net/echo  - `<?= "firstname", " ", "name" ?>`

Comment: How are the `mysql`, `sql` and `phpmyadmin` tags related to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?= $first_name, " ", $last_name ?>
```